# Will throw error in http functions causing a cold start?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

If i put this line in http `onCall` functions.

```
export const example = https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
   throw new https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "Authentication is required");
});
```

Will this causing a cold start? If will how do I tell the client if this call has an error?

Comment: There are too few context. Can you share a minimal reproductible sample?

Comment: Your code is weird. You throw an exception in all the cases?